# CakePHP save multiple data

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp, model, view

I wrote a custom view which looks like this:
http://img405.imageshack.us/i/taula.jpg/

This is my controller function with NO save data implemented yet:
http://pastebin.com/cU5rprFB

And here is my view:
http://pastebin.com/4bYLPp4z

I thought that writing form imput like this:

```
<td>
<input name="data[Linea][0][proyecto_id]" type="hidden" value=" <?php echo $proyecto['Proyecto']['id'] ?>" />
<input name="data[Linea][0][hito_id]" type="hidden" value=" <?php echo $proyecto['Hito']['id'] ?>" />
<input name="data[Linea][0][tarea_id]" type="hidden" value=" <?php echo $proyecto['Tarea']['id'] ?>" />
<input name="data[Linea][0][total_horas]" type="text" id="LineaTotalHotas" value="" >
</td>
```

would be sufficient... but it isn't. In the debug_kit I see that hidden data is OK but the data from the input is lost...

Does anyone have an example or something to help me?

---

UPDATE: I'm trying something like that in my controller:

```
function addhoras() {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        xdebug_break();
        foreach($this->data['Linea'] as $l) {
            if ( ($l['total_horas'] != 0) && ( $l['total_horas']!=NULL ) ) {
                $this->Linea->create();
                if ( $this->Linea->save($l) ) {

                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Arazonbat eon dek', true));
                }
            }
        }
        //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'addhoras'));
    }
```

But I'm getting a setflash on the `if ( $this->Linea->save($l) )`  line... so it is not saving any data... this is the `var_dump($l)`:

```
array
'proyecto_id' => string ' 1' (length=2)

'hito_id' => string ' 3' (length=2)

'usuario_id' => string ' 1' (length=2)

'fecha' => string '2011-01-01 ' (length=11)

'total_horas' => string '33' (length=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure you construct your array correctly http://book.cakephp.org/view/83/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM

And if you are saving related data remember to use saveAll instead of save.

Make sure that the array you pass to the "save" method has the typical Cake structure. This would be something like this:

```
array
(
    [Modelo] => array
    (
         [celda] => valor
    )
)
```

And remember that if you want to save related data (either HasMany or HasAndBelongsToMany ..) you must use "saveAll" instead of "save"

http://book.cakephp.org/view/83/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM